# Lambda calculus novice seeking help with defining isempty for list representation

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, computer-science, computability, lambda-calculus

I'm exploring the concept of untyped lambda calculus and I'm facing a challenge with defining the isempty function. I have a few definitions that I'm working with, which are:

```
true = λ xy. x
false = λ xy. y
nil = λ x. x
pair = λ xyb. b x y
```

Based on these definitions, a list is constructed by combining `nil` (e.g. `(pair x nil)`) and `pair` (e.g. `(pair x (pair y nil))`). I initially thought that I could define `isempty` as `(λ x. x True ???)` since `nil` evaluates to `true`. However, the resulting list from a non-empty list would be in the form `(True x y)`, which makes it unclear what to do when neither `true` nor `false` can be assigned to `x` and `y`.

I'm hoping to get some guidance on how to approach defining the isempty function within the context of untyped lambda calculus.

Comment: https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~horwitz/CS704-NOTES/2.LAMBDA-CALCULUS-PART2.html

Answer (score 3):

Given the definitions of $\mathsf{true}, \ \mathsf{false}, \ \mathsf{nil}, \ \mathsf{pair}$ in the OP, a $\lambda$-term representing the function that tests if a list is empty is the following:

$$\mathsf{isempty} = \lambda l. l \, (\lambda x \lambda y.\mathsf{true}) \,\mathsf{false} \, \mathsf{false}$$

Indeed, when $\mathsf{isempty}$ is applied to the empty list, that is, to the $\lambda$-term $\mathsf{nil}$, then $\mathsf{isempty} \, \mathsf{nil} \to_\beta^* \mathsf{true}$ because

\begin{align}
\mathsf{isempty} \, \mathsf{nil} 
&= (\lambda l. l \, (\lambda x \lambda y.\mathsf{true}) \,\mathsf{false} \, \mathsf{false}) \, \mathsf{nil}
\\
&\to_\beta \mathsf{nil} \, (\lambda xy.\mathsf{true}) \, \mathsf{false} \, \mathsf{false}
\\
&= (\lambda x.x) \, (\lambda xy.\mathsf{true}) \, \mathsf{false} \, \mathsf{false}
\\
&\to_\beta (\lambda xy.\mathsf{true}) \, \mathsf{false} \, \mathsf{false}
\\
&\to_\beta (\lambda y.\mathsf{true}) \, \mathsf{false}
\\
&\to_\beta \mathsf{true}
\end{align}

When $\mathsf{isempty}$ is instead applied to a non-empty list, that is, to a $\lambda$-term of the form $\mathsf{pair} \, M \, N$, then $\mathsf{isempty} \, (\mathsf{pair} \, M \, N) \to_\beta^* \mathsf{false}$ because

\begin{align}
\mathsf{isempty} \, (\mathsf{pair} \, M \, N) 
&= (\lambda l. l \, (\lambda x \lambda y.\mathsf{true}) \,\mathsf{false} \, \mathsf{false}) \, (\mathsf{pair} \, M \, N)
\\
&\to_\beta (\mathsf{pair} \, M \, N) \, (\lambda xy.\mathsf{true}) \, \mathsf{false} \, \mathsf{false}
\\
&= ((\lambda xyb.bxy) \, M \, N)\, (\lambda xy.\mathsf{true}) \, \mathsf{false} \, \mathsf{false}
\\
&\to_\beta ((\lambda yb.b\, My) \, N)\, (\lambda xy.\mathsf{true}) \, \mathsf{false} \, \mathsf{false}
\\
&\to_\beta (\lambda b.b \, MN)\, (\lambda xy.\mathsf{true}) \, \mathsf{false} \, \mathsf{false}
\\
&\to_\beta (\lambda xy.\mathsf{true}) \, M N \, \mathsf{false} \, \mathsf{false}
\\
&\to_\beta (\lambda y.\mathsf{true}) \, N\, \mathsf{false} \, \mathsf{false}
\\
&\to_\beta \mathsf{true} \, \mathsf{false} \, \mathsf{false}
\\
&= (\lambda x y. x) \, \mathsf{false} \, \mathsf{false}
\\
&\to_\beta (\lambda y.  \mathsf{false} )\, \mathsf{false}
\\
&\to_\beta \mathsf{false}
\end{align}